# Calculating estimated runtime and charging time for a Linux system battery in a command-line project

Tags: linux, bash, battery, arch-linux, battery-life

I am working on a command-line project in Arch Linux, specifically designed to present system battery information. I have successfully implemented various features, but I am currently facing difficulties in calculating two specific metrics:

**Estimated runtime**: I would like to calculate the estimated time that my laptop will run on its current usage. Is there a way to determine this information programmatically in a Linux environment?

**Charging time:** Additionally, I would like to calculate the amount of time it will take for my laptop's battery to reach a full charge, considering the current input or power supply. Is there a reliable method to determine this information programmatically on a Linux system?

I have searched extensively for relevant resources, but I haven't found a comprehensive solution tailored to my specific project requirements. Therefore, I would greatly appreciate any guidance, code examples,

**Thank you in advance for your valuable assistance!**

Comment: *I haven't found a comprehensive solution* - this implies you've found part solutions, perhaps combining the parts will make a whole?

Comment: solution includes depending on some other tools which i don't find optimal because i m making a simple script just like pfetch.

Comment: so you want a solution that doesn't depend on any other tools?

Comment: yes, like using files in /sys/class/power_supply/BAT*/. Here i have most of the battery information.

Comment: `Here i have most of the battery information` what's missing

Comment: You should fill your question with more details instead of sending them in comments.

Comment: Thankyou for sharing you views, i will keep this in mind from now onwards.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.